# Patch statement not patching to sharepoint list, Power Apps

Tags: list, function, sharepoint, patch, powerapps

My Patch statement is not updating the list item, it is also not giving an error so I am not sure where it is failing.

```
Patch('Check-In Data', First(Filter('Check-In Data', Title = "nNumberLookUp.text" && 'Active Issue'=true)), {Feedback:Feedback_DataCard4.DataField, Sat:DataCardValue37.Value, 'Active Issue':false}); Navigate(Completed, ScreenTransition.Fade)
```

it should be looking up the n-number then adding those two fields and turning active issue to false.  But nothing happens